# React on AWS Amplify, Code in AWS CodeCommit - CustomerError: Artifact directory doesn't exist: build

Tags: reactjs, npm, aws-amplify

I am trying to figure out why the directory for my build can't be found. I have tried many versions that I found on other pages `./myapp/build`, `build`, `./build/`. I have tried `cd`ing into the folder. I am hosting my code in AWS CodeCommit.

I am at a loss. I am not a front-end developer, so maybe I am missing something very simple here. It loads locally perfectly fine.

[image: the error on line 68]

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

`amplify.yml`

```json
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build commands
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
        commands:
            - echo 'BEFORE BUILD'
            - ls
            - npm run build
            - echo 'AFTER BUILD'
            - ls
  artifacts:
    # IMPORTANT - Please verify your build output directory
    baseDirectory: /myapp/build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths: 
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Answer (score 0):

I had luck following [this tutorial](https://aws.amazon.com/getting-started/hands-on/build-react-app-amplify-graphql/module-one/?e=gs2020&p=build-a-react-app-intro) integrating github and amplify. Also here is my buildspec for reference as well : )

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have already used this, but when using CodeCommit, I am having issues. Even with the exact `amplify.yml` as you.